# spring-social 1.1.0.RELEASE pulling in snapshot dependencies

Tags: spring-social

Trying to upgrade from spring-social-twitter `1.1.0.M4` to `1.1.0.RELEASE`. The RELEASE version pulls in multiple snapshot dependencies during maven build. This does not happen with 1.1.0.M4.

`Downloading: org/springframework/social/spring-social-config/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: org/springframework/social/spring-social-core/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: org/springframework/social/spring-social-web/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with Spring Social Facebook 1.1.0.RELEASE (which is why there is a Spring Social Facebook 1.1.1.RELEASE to remedy that problem). But it shouldn't be a problem with Spring Social Twitter 1.1.0.RELEASE. In fact, I just took a look at the POM for Spring Social Twitter 1.1.0.RELEASE at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/social/spring-social-twitter/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-social-twitter-1.1.0.RELEASE.pom and it's clear that it transitively depends on Spring Social Core/Config/Security 1.1.0.RELEASE.

Moreover, you say that spring-social-web 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is pulled in. Spring Social Twitter does not depend on spring-social-web at all, so it's not the problem.

Is it possible that you also have Spring Social Facebook 1.1.0.RELEASE as a dependency? If so, then try Spring Social Facebook 1.1.1.RELEASE and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: My apologies, we were indeed also using spring social facebook 1.1.0.RELEASE. Changed to 1.1.1.RELEASE as suggested and now it's all good (in fact we had the same version for both twitter and facebook spring social artifacts, will be more careful in future)

Comment: No worries. Glad to hear that you got it working. Just know that although the Spring Social projects seem to follow each other closely with regard to version numbers, they are versioned independently so that each can react to bugs or changes in their targeted APIs without requiring releases across all Spring Social projects.